# Как добавить значения из json в одинаковые div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

В общем имеется код для добавления значений из json в div блоки

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'ajax/prop',
 dataType: 'html',
 success:function(data){
 var jsonStr = JSON.parse(data);
 const container= document.getElementById('prop');
 jsonStr.forEach(function(item) {
 const itemDiv = document.createElement('button');
 itemDiv.classList.add('btn');
 itemDiv.id = item.id;
 let innerHtml = '<dl>';
 Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
 innerHtml += `
  <dd>${item[key]}<dd>
;
});
innerHtml += '</dl>';
itemDiv.innerHTML = innerHtml;
container.appendChild(itemDiv);
});
}
});`
```

Но проблема в том что все значения добавляются только в первый div, а мне нужно что бы первое значение из json добавилось в первый div, второе во второй и т.д.
Вот строка из json.
`{"id":"1","time":"2 минуты"},{"id":"2","button":"Купить"},{"id":"3","back":"Вернуть"},{"id":"4","time":"1 минута"}`

Comment: добавить какие-нибудь условия не пробовали?

Comment: Код не похож на рабочий. В dataType можно указать json, а не html и не делать парсинга.

Comment: если у вас объект - вы можете перебирать просто его и по индексу выводить, если массив, то тогда по индексу не стоит)

Comment: @Павел - обьект, но я незнаю куда вставить цикл для перебора обьектов с одним классом